# Why only two dihedral angles for a snub dodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, angle, polyhedra

The Wikipedia page for the [snub dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron) provides explicit coordinates for its vertices, from which one can of course by brute force calculate that there are only two dihedral angles. Can anyone give a (hopefully insightful/more intuitive) shorter proof that there must be only two such angles? The symmetries of the object immediately imply that there can be at most three such angles: the triangle-pentagon one, the angle between two triangles each of which is adjacent to a pentagon, and the angle between a triangle not adjacent to any pentagon and one that is. But is there any "quick" way to see that the latter two angles must be equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Focus on a pair of adjacent triangles $T_1$ and $T_2$. Their vertices
lie on the circumscribing sphere $S$. Their dihedral angle is
supplementary to the angle $\angle P_1OP_2$ where $O$ is the centre
of $S$ and $P_i$ is the centroid of $T_i$. But this angle only depends
on the radius of the sphere and the edge lengths of the equilateral triangles $T_i$. (There's a rotation of the sphere taking $T_1$ and $T_2$
to any configuration of two adjacent 
triangles with the same sidelengths with vertices on $S$.)

Comment: Aha! I was not recognizing the fact that a symmetry of the circumsphere demonstrating the equality of two triangle-triangle dihedrals does not have to be a symmetry of the full snub dodecahedron. Thanks!